# ordered build of nested docker images with compose

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I am building a lamp with docker-compose.

In my docker-compose.yml i have the following:

```
ubuntu-base:
    build: ./ubuntu-base

webserver-base:
    build: ./webserver-base
```

webserver-base is derived from the ubuntu-base image.
In webserver-base Dockerfile:

```
FROM docker_ubuntu-base
```

ubuntu-base is built

```
FROM ubuntu:14.04
```

Now, if i execute the docker-compose.yml, it does not build the ubuntu-base image, but its trying to build the webserver-base image and fails, because it does not find the ubuntu-base image.

Output:

```
$ docker-compose up -d
Building webserver-base
Step 1 : FROM docker_ubuntu-base
Pulling repository docker.io/library/docker_ubuntu-base
ERROR: Service 'webserver-base' failed to build: Error: image library/docker_ubuntu-base:latest not found
```

It all works if i build the ubuntu-base image manually first.

why does it not build the ubuntu-base image?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sadly, build ordering is a missing feature in docker-compose, that is requested for many month now.

As workaround you can link the containers like this:

```
ubuntu-base:
    build: ./ubuntu-base

webserver-base:
    build: ./webserver-base
    links:
      - ubuntu-base
```

this way ubuntu-base gets built before webserver-base.

Comment: Hi, thanks for tip. Today is 2016, did you found any better way?

Comment: hmm, may by i'm misunderstood, but depends_on does not affect on build order. I'll try it later, still interesting in this feature.

Comment: ok, please share your results. since i did not test this myself, but only read about it in https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/295, i will change my answer according to your feedback. Or write an answer yourself, i will vote it up

Answer (score 3):

First do a

```
docker-compose build ubuntu-base
```

But this will not create the image docker_ubuntu-base locally because you do not have any build steps. Only docker.io/ubuntu:14.04 will be downloaded.

If you add a build step like:

```
FROM ubuntu:14.04
RUN date
```

A docker_ubuntu-base image will be created.

So first do a:

```
docker-compose build ubuntu-base
```

This will create the image docker_ubuntu-base. Then you can do a `docker-compose build`.

But I would advise against this nested-docker image construction. This is cumbersome because as @kev indicated you have no control over the order of the builds. Why don't you create two independent docker files? Let docker derive webserver-base from ubuntu-base by keeping the Dockerfile instructions as identical as possible and reusing the layers.